# Create function with a parameter, which will become the part of IN (1, 2, 3) clause

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, parameter

Following is the part of function declaration. Unfortunately it doesn't work the way I would like it to.

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_cool_func(some_parameter INTEGER, some_other_parameter INTEGER[])
RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
STABLE 

AS $BODY$

DECLARE count_entries INTEGER;

BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(some_table.id) INTO count_entries FROM some_table
    WHERE ...
    AND some_table.some_integer_field IN (some_other_parameter);

        IF (count_entries > 0) THEN...
```

`some_other_parameter` is a list of integer values (1, 2, 3).

My questions:

1. Is this function declaration correct?
2. How do I define the default value for `some_other_parameter`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `= ANY` instead of `IN`

```
AND some_table.some_integer_field = ANY (some_other_parameter);
```

The equivalent of NOT IN would be `<> ALL (...)`

To declare a parameter with a [default value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_cool_func(..., p_id_list INTEGER[] default array[42])
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is there any way to provide a default value for `some_other_parameter`? And, how can the `NOT IN (...)` be substituted by `ANY`? Like  `<> ANY (some_other_parameter)`?

Comment: @Alexander: see my edit